# uiautomator DumpWindowHierarchy function does not produce right screen XML

Tags: android, xml, layout, dump, android-uiautomator

My goal is to generate the XML of every screen while navigating through the emulator.
So my original thought was to run shell command `uiautomator dump` while the test is running. `uiautomator dump` did produced the complete XML of the current screen. However, the program immediately stopped after the command is executed due to the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomationService not connected.
>   Did you call #register()?

Therefore, I switched to using the built-in function `DumpWindowHierarchy` in the `UiDevice` class. Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. Although the program can proceed properly without being disconnected, `DumpWindowHierarchy` doesn't produce the correct XML of the current screen.

Any thoughts on the solution? Is there any other way to capture the XML of current screen while executing the uitest. Or at least how to solve the `UiAutomationService not connected` bug during program execution.

Comment: What is "the XML of each screen"? What is "the right XML of the current screen"?

Comment: The hierarchy layout of the screen that is currently displayed on the emulator. However when I tried to `DumpWindowHierarchy` on a certain screen, the function failed to generate the XML layout because some tags were missing.

Comment: Like it could generate the XML file of a totally different screen (the default home screen of the app).

Comment: I have the same problem, was your problem solved?